# Как найти минимальное основание системы счисления?

Tags: алгоритм

Задача "Инопланетянин"

Во время эксперимента Накодиллы было случайно получено сообщение инопланетян , содержащее формулу вида A + B = C.
Общественности стало интересно , какую же систему счисления использую инопланетяне. Так как внеземная цивилизация была достаточно развита, чтобы отправить межпланетное сообщение , Накодилла предположил, что основание системы счисления довольно мало. Требуется написать программу, которая находит минимальное основание системы счисления, при котором данное равенство выполняется.

ФОРМАТ ВВОДА : 
В единственной строке входных данных содержится три числа A , B и C. Числа состоят из цифр от 0 до 9 и заглавных латинских букв от A до Z.

ФОРМАТ ВЫВОДА : 
Требуется вывести единственное число - искомое основание системы счисления. Если такой системы счисления не существует , то вывести -1. Гарантируется, что ответ не превышает 36.

Пример ввода : 2 2 4 
Пример вывода : 5

Пример ввода : 1A 2 20 
Пример вывода : 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простейший вариант:

1) Пишем функцию преобразования системы счисления (см. учебник по математике или информатике)
Формат:

```
int: changeBaseToDec(str: count,int: base_in){
//преобразование В десятичную
}
```

2) минимальное основание системы счисления (MIN_BASE) гарантированно больше, чем самая большая цифра, соответственно, пробегаемся циклом по примеру, выискивая максимальную "цифру".

3)

```
for(i=MIN_BASE; i<=36; i++){
if((changeBaseToDec(A,i)+changeBaseToDec(B,i))==changeBaseToDec(C,i)){
return i;
}
}
return -1;//Сюда мы придем, если не найдем ответа.
```

Собственно, все. Не уверен, правда, что самый оптимальный.

P.S. кто сказал, что у инопланетян цифры и буквы расположены в том же порядке, что и у нас?
В этом случае придется заняться гораздо более масштабным перебором: вам придется перебрать все последовательности всех букв. Это, в нашем случае,
36! возможных вариантов = 3.72 × 10^41
Компу такое быстро перебрать слабо. По крайней мере, за время олимпиады.(на хорошем десктопном проце это будет 10^16 миллиардов лет) Так что вероятность контакта 1/36! =)

Answer (score 2):

Переведём все строки-числа в массивы со значениями их цифр. Запишем их задом-наперед. Более короткие дополним нулями:

```
A: 1A -> [10, 1]
B: 2  -> [ 2, 0]
C: 20 -> [ 0, 2]
```

Пройдемся слева направо имитируя сложение в столбик. Рассмотрим сумму младших разрядов: если бы переноса не возникло, то `A[0] + B[0] == C[0]`. Это не так (`10 + 2 != 0`). Значит есть перенос и `A[0] + B[0] == base + C[0]`. Можно вычислить основание системы счисления.

В следующем разряде нужно учесть пришедший перенос: `A[1] + B[1] + carry == C[1]`. Равенство выполнено, проверять основание не надо.

Продвигаясь по разрядам выполняем сложение в столбик. При каждом переносе проверяем основание - все переносы должны дать один результат. Кроме этого основание должно быть больше всех цифр в во всех трёх числах.

```
def read_number(s):
    alphabet = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    return list(map(alphabet.index, reversed(s)))


def align(lists):
    max_length = max(map(len, lists))
    for l in lists:
        l.extend([0] * (max_length - len(l)))


def determine_base(a, b, c):
    align((a, b, c))
    max_digit = max(a + b + c)
    base = None
    carry = 0
    for ai, bi, ci in zip(a, b, c):
        s = ai + bi + carry
        if s < ci:
            return -1
        if s > ci:
            if base is None:
                base = s - ci
                if base <= max_digit:
                    return -1
            if s - ci != base:
                return -1
            carry = 1
        else:
            carry = 0
    if carry != 0:
        return -1
    if base is None:
        return max_digit + 1
    return base

    
def main():
    a, b, c = tuple(map(read_number, input().split()))
    print(determine_base(a, b, c))


main()
```